# How to change the priority(nice value) of an android service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-source, nice

I am porting Android P in a device, in that I have seen some lags in the systemui(com.android.systemui) especially in volume bar actions.

So I increased the priority of systemui using renice command it works better after that. So now I want to add the priority while the process starts.

Please help me in change the priority of the systemui when it launches.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `priority` property to the service description in its `.rc` file.

> priority
>
> Scheduling priority of the service process. This value has to be in range -20 to 19. Default priority is 0. Priority is set via setpriority().

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md